# How to get Total Page Count in Reportviewer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, rdlc

I am developing an window application where i need to get total pages in Rdlc report viewer.

So please tell me how to get total page count.

Here is my Code, which is not working and always show 0 :

```
Dim TotalPage As Integer = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.GetTotalPages(PageCountMode.Actual)
MsgBox(TotalPageAs)
```

[image]

In this image total number of page is 6 .

Comment: Typically, you need to produce the pages to know how many there will be.  At least run through the pagination logic to get a count.  Perhaps a simulated print cycle to get a count, prior to actually producing the preview?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ServerReport and not the LocalReport, as shown here:

```
ReportViewer.ServerReport.GetTotalPages()
```

For more information, take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9fc7120-4560-4f43-8ab1-c745ba11cbdf/how-to-get-the-total-of-pages-of-the-reportviewer?forum=vsreportcontrols) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252234(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: I am developing window application and my database is mysql not SQL Server